# How to solve OperationalError without deleting the db - django 2.0

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, models

I have run done these:

1. delete all files under migrations (except **init**)

2.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

and even

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

3. delete db.sqlite3

Thankfully, it solved the problem. However, I had to do step 3 to solve this.

How do you solve this problem without deleting the database since I can't afford to do such later on when I already have too much data?

Or what causes this problem? Thanks

EDIT:

Error is OperationalError - no such table

Comment: You haven't said what caused the operational error in the first place?

Comment: Any details on the error?

Comment: i edited it. sorry for the lacking details

Comment: Yes, but what did you do to cause the operational error?

Comment: Hmmmm. I was just adding models and applying migrations. Then in the admin interface, some models were working and some are throwing this error.

Comment: This would happen if you haven't created/applied migrations for model changes - hard to say much more without knowing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: everytime i add new models, i do makemigrations and migrate respectively. Then this error is being thrown. What I did was delete all the migrations and run the commands again (makemigrations and migrate) but the error is still there. The next thing I did was delete the database, re-applied the migrations and it worked

Comment: Backup and test on a copy DB.

Comment: When you add a new model to existing app, create migrations with the name of the app and then migrate it.

python manage.py makemigrations app_name
python manage.py migrate